# cannot add UIButton to tableView section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have this code

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 45))
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 12.5, width: tableView.frame.width - 100, height: 20))
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.font = UIFont(name: "SFProDisplay-Bold", size: 18);
        label.textColor = UIColor.darkGray

        let sectionName: String
        switch section {
            case 0:
                sectionName = NSLocalizedString("   Featured", comment: "featured")
            case 1:
                sectionName = NSLocalizedString("   Trending", comment: "trending")
            // ...
            default:
                sectionName = NSLocalizedString("   New", comment: "new")
        }
        label.text = sectionName
        label.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
        headerView.addSubview(label)

        let button:UIButton = UIButton(
            frame: CGRect(x: tableView.bounds.size.width-100,
                          y: 12.5,
                          width: 100,
                          height: 20))
        button.setTitle("More", for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
//        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnShowHideTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

        button.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
        headerView.addSubview(button)

        return headerView
    }
```

I am trying to add the UIButton to the tableView header, but it is not working. Does anyone know why?

The UIButton does not show up why the label does.

Comment: Define "not working". Please [edit] your question with specific details about in what way exactly this code isn't doing what you expect. Do not reply in a comment.

Comment: Is the button there but inactive or is it not even visible?

Comment: Works fine. I gave the button a green background, and it clearly shows up in the simulator. I enabled the target selector and it works too. I've voted to close.

Comment: @BartvanKuik how about the button text color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line does not work:

```
button.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
```

Replace it with the following line:

```
button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
```